# Find time complexity of recursive function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

Assignment is to show that the time complexity is Ω(2<sup>max(n,m)</sup>) in the worst case scenario for following recursive function.

Assume the following:

- n = w1len (length of word w1),
- m = w2len (length of word w2)

Here is the code

```
int dist(String w1, String w2, int w1len, int w2len) {
    if (w1len == 0) {
        return w2len;
    }
    if (w2len == 0) {
        return w1len;
    }   
    int res = dist(w1, w2, w1len - 1, w2len - 1) + (w1.charAt(w1len - 1) == w2.charAt(w2len - 1) ? 0 : 1);      
    int addLetter = dist(w1, w2, w1len - 1, w2len) + 1;
    if (addLetter < res)
        res = addLetter;
    int deleteLetter = dist(w1, w2, w1len, w2len - 1) + 1;
    if (deleteLetter < res)
        res = deleteLetter;

    return res;
}
```

Comment: @chepner sorry if unclear. I want to know how to show that the time complexity is O(2^(max(n,m)))

Comment: A good starting point would be to trace the number of recursive calls for inputs of various lengths.

Comment: This seems to me as standard edit distance problem. The recursive solution complexity is 2^max(m,n) can be changed to n*m, if I remember correctly, using dynamic programming.

Comment: It should read big oh, not omega.

Answer (score 1):

Try to draw call tree for the function.
What does it look like?
Can you estimate the number of invocation of dist function?

Comment: @Nishant I disagree.  For a question like that, the answer would be a hint as to how to procede with solving the homework.  I don't like answers to homework questions which can be just copy/pasted and submitted for grade.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. To me, it's the standard way -- and the one likely the OP knows. What would be better to me is make me visualize how the recursive tree is splitting. You don't have to calculate. He will do that part. The problem is,  I also have problem visualizing the tree. But I know process. Anyway. This was my reason to call it comment, because it does not add anything worth while wrt this question. it's a general comment true for any recursive algorithm.